# pg_cron jobs are not being executed

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks, pg-cron

We have installed **pg_cron** extension on PostgreSQL 13 database.

`postgresql.conf` file:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'pg_cron_db_name'
```

Also we enabled trust authentication for connections coming from localhost in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
#IPv4 local connections:
host   db_name    postgres,pg_cron_user    127.0.0.1/32         trust
host   all        all                      0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

We have run this query from `postgres` user to schedule a simple job for a database `db_name` (other than the one **pg_cron** was installed in):

```sql
SELECT cron.schedule_in_database('job1', '5,10,20,30 17 * * *', $$SELECT 1$$, 'db_name');
```

Everythings works fine on our staging database. 
But on our production DB the job is never executed. Table `cron.job_run_details` is empty and there are no entries in a logfile (even error ones).
Versions of production and staging DBs are the same. We performed identical steps to set up **pg_cron**. The only difference we can think of is that staging DB is running on on-premise server while production DB is running on Azure's virtual machine.

We tried to switch to unix domain socket to allow connections from localhost by running:

```sql
UPDATE cron.job SET nodename = '' WHERE jobid = <job_id>;
```

This helped, but temporarily. Job has been successfully executed three times and after that stopped to run again.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem are appreciated.

Comment: @jjanes We have waited for three days and then checked the job again. There still were no new records in job_run_details table and no new logs from pg_cron in log file. So I assume the reason why our job is not executed is not in schedule plan ;(

Comment: What OS and version? What version of pg_cron do you have?  How did you install it (both PostgreSQL and pg_cron)?

Comment: If you run `ps -efl` do you see a process title including "pg_cron launcher", or that string for a backend_type in pg_stat_activity?

Comment: @jjanes OS Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. We upgraded earlier our PostgreSQL db from 10 to 13 version. pg_cron extension was installed using [apt.postgresql.org](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron#installing-pg_cron). pg_cron version is 1.5. I can see 'pg_cron launcher' while runing  `ps -efl`. It is present in pg_stat_activity table as well.

Comment: Even if the job is failing, it should be leaving entries in cron.job_run_details (as well as the db log file), so I don't know what could be going on.  I'd create a new task which runs every minute, to expand debugging opportunities, then `strace` the pg_cron launcher process to see if it is actually doing anything.